# Default php.ini macOs Catalina

Tags: php, macos, apache, macos-catalina

I would like to know which php.ini is the default one used by PHP ?

Because if you write locate php.ini there a 3 files and all of these files have an /etc as parent directory, but not the same parent directory of /etc, so I don't know which one is the default one used by PHP. [Terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itjIK.png)

Comment: Copy and paste your terminal output into post.

Comment: I shared the output with you threw a screenshot which is linked with the words : "Terminal output" and can't paste it here because there are layout problems.

Answer (score 6):

Type in your console:

```
php -i |grep php\.ini
```

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way ist to check out the ini path on the phpinfo() Call

Simply edit your index.php

```
<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

Comment: Have already done this, if you haven't created the php.ini there is written no value. Maybe I have to specify my question, where is the default configuration of PHP. Because you can use it (and make the phpinfo() command) without creating a php.ini from one of the templates.

Comment: Checked it on my MacBook: /private/etc/php.ini.default

Answer (score 0):

On macOS Catalina

type

1. localhost/phpmyadmin into browser
2. click PHPInfo on menu
3. ctrl+f "php.ini"