# Cannot find the PHP.ini for activating extension=php_intl.dll for cakePHP with XAMPP

Tags: php, cakephp, xampp, macos-catalina, intl

I'm going through the installation guide here (https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/installation.html) and I'm at the point where I have to uncomment extension=php_intl.dll. I cannot even find the php.ini file.

I have checked the php_info() page on localhost of XAMPP and the directory it says it's in doesn't exist.

Any suggestions please? I have been looking at a variety of other installing guides for macOS Catalina with XAMPP for cakePHP but I have not found this php.ini files yet.

Comment: I believe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684609/where-can-i-find-php-ini

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default php.ini macOs Catalina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59282952/default-php-ini-macos-catalina)

Comment: Sugestion. Use docker for example this starter stack https://devilbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ or your own lamp stack, or vagrant box, or use natve php installed on your macos

Comment: Yes I have it sorted now. Thanks!